# Enabling SSL on Tomcat 9

Tags: ssl, tomcat, pki

There are a few questions I have regarding setting up SSL on Tomcat 9 as some of the things I've read have some inconsistencies and I'm also new to PKI. Ultimately, there are two things I'm trying to accomplish: enable SSL on Tomcat 9 for a secure websocket on a webserver and also locally for testing.

**Tomcat Configuration**

In server.xml, it already has a Connector commented out for SSL which looks like this

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">
    <SSLHostConfig>
        <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="conf/localhost-rsa.jks"
                     type="RSA" />
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

On the Tomcat's "how-to", and every other article, the Connector looks like this

```
<Connector
    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
    port="8443" maxThreads="200"
    scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
    keystoreFile="${user.home}/.keystore" keystorePass="changeit"
    clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

I'm not sure which configuration to use, or even if there is a different protocol I should use. Also it seems that the connector is the only Tomcat configuration necessary, but let me know if I'm wrong.

**Keystore**

The webserver already uses SSL for HTTPS on Apache. Since it would be the same domain, would it be an issue to use the same certificate for Tomcat/WSS too? If not, Apache uses a domain.crt, domain.key, My_CA_Bundle.ca-bundle, and ca-bundle.crt.

For the local installation, I used mkcert to create a certificate for localhost which produced localhost.pem and localhost-key.pem.

Again, I'm new to PKI. I'm not sure if I need to use a Java Keystore file, if it can use a different file type, etc. Any help would be greatly appreciated.